How to get file path in nextjs 13?
This is the code which is working perfectly fine in development:
const apnProvider = () => {
  return new apn.Provider({
    token: {
      key: path.join(process.cwd(), "src/lib/credentials/AuthKey.p8"),
      keyId: "",
      teamId: "",
    },
    production: true,
  })
}

But the issue started when I deployed to Vercel. It started showing the error:
Error: l [VError]: Failed loading token key: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/src/lib/credentials/AuthKey.p8'

Please let me know how I can solve the issue and get the file path in Next.js 13.

I think this could be useful for you: https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions
